# Removing images from modal dynamically with the help of JS/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage there are Gridster widgets which have multiple images in them. Images can be added with `+` button.

When I press `+` a modal opens in which user can  multiple images and on clicking `Add Image` those images get added on widgets.

The images on widgets have there addresses in a `textarea` on widgets with `class=imagenames`

**What I want to achieve**

When modal opens it currently shows all the images.But I want that modal to show only those images of all the images which are not there on that particular widget

**What my approach was**

When I click `+` button a function `$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function()` gets open I was trying to extract the `textarea` with class `imagenames` and then delete the that image so that image wont be shown.

Images are in the form

```
 <div class="modal-body">

      <!--  Images which I retrieve from backend for now they are 
      hardcoded paths and actually are dynamic(No fixed number)-->


<div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl" src="https://cdnd.icons8.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Run-Command-100.png"></div>
      <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl" src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/chapel.png"></div>
      <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl"src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/boy.png"></div>
      <div class="outerdiv"><img class="img-fl"src="https://png.icons8.com/metro/2x/wacom-tablet.png"></div>

      </div>
```

The function which get triggered when `+` button is pressed

```
  $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
        parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    });

    $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');
        if (parentdiv.hasClass('preselect')) {

            parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');
            selectedImageSRC = selectedImageSRC.replace($(this).attr('src'),"");
            selectedImageSRC = trimChar(selectedImageSRC, ',');
            selectedImageSRC = (selectedImageSRC.replace(/,,/g , ","));
            console.log("In remove");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in remove");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }else {

            parentdiv.addClass('preselect');

            if (selectedImageSRC === '') {

                selectedImageSRC += $(this).attr('src');

            } else {

                selectedImageSRC += ',' + $(this).attr('src');
            }

            console.log("In add");
            console.log(selectedImageSRC);
            console.log("Parent Div in Add");
            console.log(parentdiv);
        }     
});
```

I wanted to somehow edit the above function so that every time modal is opened it will show images dynamically depending upon images on widget

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2d85j15/) which represents entire work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these line to you code after `$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');` in`$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function()`.

**code snippet**

```
$(".outerdiv").find('img').closest('div').css({"display":"inline-block"});
parentLI.find( '.imagewrap .images' ).each(function(index,item){ 
    $(".outerdiv").find('img[src$="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"]').closest('div').css({"display":"none"});

});
```

updated jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/z684xzhn/

Comment: Is there a way by which the images in modal will appear one after another.Currently it shows gap in the images

Comment: @Rookie_123 yes.. it can .. Check the jsfiddle now

Comment: Can you just explain what is the logic of above code

Comment: @Rookie_123. I just try to hide the images from the model that are present in `imagewrap` element by taking the src of each image.

Comment: And about the making them display one after another even in image between two images is present on the widget.(The thing which I asked in first comment) how you doing it

Comment: If you give display as none for the div containing image. It won't take any space. i.e. if an element style given as display as none. It won't take any space in ui.